# Integrate Visual Studio Coded UI Test with VSTS/TFS Build pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to integrate VS Coded UI Test in VSTS/TFS build pipeline to test a Visual Studio Extension, however I could not find reference for this in MSDN, Is this possible with TFS 2015.2 and VSTS?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use [Visual Studio Test Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azdevops) since [Run Functional Test Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/run-functional-tests?view=azdevops) is deprecated.

Use version 2.x or higher of the Visual Studio Test task together with phases to run unit and functional tests on the universal agent.

For more details, see [Testing with unified agents and phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azdevops&tabs=yaml#run-your-tests).

Comment: Hi Kamil Kh,
Your link to "Visual Studio Test Task" is broken. Can you edit your answer so it points to the correct website? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** You can use the [Run Functional Test task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests).
This task will distribute your tests with test method granularity to a pool of test agent machines.

Description of usage of this task:

- Copy the assemblies of the Coded UI to the machines where you  run the tests; on this machines you will install the test agents too;
- Before the Run Functional test you must use the [Deploy Test Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) which will download/install/configure the test agent on all target machines.
- Since you need to run Coded UI test you need to set the checkbox for "Interactive Process", as the agent will run as an interactive process (and not as a service) in order to interoperate with the desktop entities.
- After the deployment, invoke the Run Functional test by either:

  - selecting with an appropriate minimatch the assemblies you to run you previously copied to the test machines;
  - select the test plan and the test suite containing the test cases with a filled Associated Automation.

For the prerequisites to run the tasks check the documentation by following the links above.

Comment: Thanks @Luca Cappa, Is it possible to install test agent in the same machine as the TFS is installed? I found following article with different approach, what is the best option for this?

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents

Comment: on the TFS server absolutely do not put the Test Agent :-)